# CVs Job matching : neural network experiment

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, dataset

I am currently working on a learning method in order to select the best Cv for a job. I use tensorflow which seems to be efficient. But I have no data set (a list of annoted Cvs and a list of jobs with the best Cv from the data set). Do you think this kind of stuff is available ?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: start a company with the words "deep learning startup" in the description. Announce job openings on r/MachineLearning/ subreddit. Millions of CVs pour in. You've got a dataset.

Comment: Are you looking for CV documents or raw users profiles data?